# Attempt to encrypt a text file causes a TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is my code:

```
my_text= F = open("mytext.txt")
KEY=4
encoded= ""

for c in my_text:
    rem = (ord(c) - 97 + KEY) % 26
    encoded += chr(rem + 97)

print(encoded)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 21 found
```

It returns the error above but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: for the record I am a novice to this and I am not very good at coding

Comment: Quick reminder: When you `open()` a file, make sure that you `close()` it after using it. You can also use a context manager (like what was done in martineau's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53612989/1116098)) to automatically close files after use, without explicitly closing them.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a file retrieves the data line-by-line by default. You can read the file in as a stream of bytes using the two-argument from of the [`iter(callable, sentinel)`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) built-in function as shown below. Note this approach will *not* read the entire file into memory all-at-once like what would happen using something like the [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) built-in.

```
KEY = 4
encoded = ""

with open("mytext.txt", 'rb') as my_text:
    # Using iter() like below causes it to quit when read() returns an
    # empty char string (which indicates the end of the file has been
    # reached).
    for c in iter(lambda: my_text.read(1), b''):
        rem = (ord(c) - 97 + KEY) % 26
        encoded += chr(rem + 97)

print(encoded)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use readlines and do other loop for any new line in the text file. otherwise single line will be good.

```
my_text= F = open("mytext.txt")
my_text = F.readlines()
KEY = 4 
encoded= ""
for c in my_text:
    for c1 in c:
        rem = (ord(c1) - 97 + KEY) % 26 
        encoded += chr(rem + 97)

print(encoded)
```

Comment: The `my_text = F.readlines()` reads the entire file into memory at once, which really isn't necessary (nor likely desirable).

Comment: the requirements was not clear so I gave answer with least changes so the person can get the idea where he was wrong.

Comment: Yea sorry Im new to this so Im not great at this

Comment: "you have to use readlines" is incorrect. Iterating over the result of readlines will give you the same sequence of line-at-a-time strings that iterating over the file gives (as in the OPs code). Try taking out the "my_text = F.readlines()" line in your code, and this will still work. What you have actually done to solve the problem is adding the nested "for c1 in c:" loop, which will correctly process each line of the file a character at a time.